# How can I create a menu items from meta box based on users input

Tags: posts, php, functions, custom-field, metabox

I have created a metabox that takes a name that the user can give as an additional name of their post. I am wondering how I can automatically create a menu item based on the name the user input into the metabox, and set the url to #PostName?

Even if someone could guide me in the right direction on creating the menu item from a metabox on the post screen I could figure out the rest.

**EDIT:** I have added some extra info since I understand it seems a little confusing to someone who has know idea of why I want this.

I am creating a custom theme with the html5 boilerplate. It is a one page theme that users add sections to the page by adding posts. The theory is the user adds a custom name to the post into a meta box on the page and it will add the menu item with that name. Since the meta box I created already adds an ID in the html of each post with an additional ID tag the url for the menu will be #PostName. This is so when the user clicks the menu item it will automatically scroll right to the section.

In most themes the Nav menu brings you to a different page. Since my theme is only a one page theme the nav links will bring the user to the section on the page. All I am trying to accomplish is to add some automation in the theme so the users don't need to add the menu items manually.

Comment: I do not understand this question.

Comment: I want to programmatically add menu items from the post page.

Comment: A menu item for what? What menu?

Comment: Navigational menu. I am creating a custom theme with the html bootstrap. It is a one page theme that users add sections to the page by adding posts. The theory is the user adds a custom name to the post from a meta box for the menu  and it will add the menu item with that name. Since it already adds an ID in the html the url for the menu will be #PostName. This is so when the user clicks the menu item it will automatically scroll right to the section.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I have added some addition information into my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand this task: get posts (you can shape this any way you want by adding extra parameters to the query), for each post get its meta-box value (replace the key with yours), if value found add it to the menu's HTML.

**Note**: code is not tested, it is more of an outline.

```
$html = '';
$domain = 'your-domain'; // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e
$meta_key = 'your-meta-key'; // TODO replace value with yours

$post_menu_items = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'     =>  'post',
    'post_status'   =>  array( 'publish' ),
    'numberposts'   =>  -1
) );

if($post_menu_items){
    $html .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($post_menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
        $meta_title = get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, $meta_key, true);
        if(!empty($current_meta)){
            $html .='<li><a href="#' . $meta_title . '">' . $menu_item->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    $html = '</ul>';
} else {
    _e('No posts found.', $domain);
}
echo $html;
```

Thinking about it, you could even avoid the `get_post_meta` call by supplying a `meta_key` parameter into your `get_posts`. You're welcome to experiment with that.